# Using R nested lists as simple binary tree

Tags: r, tree, binary-tree, depth-first-search, nested-lists

I have a simple problem constrained to R. I have what is effectively a sort of binary tree, where only the terminal leaves have values associated with them. A toy example is visible [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAJlD.jpg)
Essentially, I perform an operation between the leaves with the greatest depth (in a tie of depth, order doesn't matter). I have made it addition here, but, in reality, they're getting plugged into a more complicated formula.
I am limited to R for my code. This structure can be represented with this command, though I obtain it via other means:

`testBranch<-list(list(list(list(20,15),40),list(10,30)),5)  #Depth of 4`

I have a working function to determine how deep the deepest level is, but nested lists in R are boggling. Any clue how to efficiently find the set of **indexes** to access the deepest values? For instance, in the toy example above

`testBranch[[1]][[1]][[1]]`

would give me what I'd like, a list containing 2 elements. Using my addition example, I could then do this:

`indexesOI<-getIndexes(testBranch)
 testBranch[indexesOI]<-testBranch[indexesOI][1]+testBranch[indexesOI][2]
 #testBranch now has depth of 3`

Resulting in the tree corresponding to step 1 in the [toy example,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAJlD.jpg) which can be represented in R by:

`testBranchStep1<-list(list(list(35,40),list(10,30)),5)`

I am open to using packages, if need be. Just not looking to rewrite a whole node class/dfs in R, as I don't have much experience with the class system. I have looked into data.tree, but have had no luck coercing my nested lists into their data structure.

Any help you can provide would be great! Pardon the hastily made ASCII trees. I am largely self-taught and haven't asked many questions here, so please let me know, too, if I need to adjust my formatting! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `data.tree`.

```
library(data.tree)
testBranch <- list(list(list(list(20,15),40),list(10,30)),5)
tree <- FromListSimple(testBranch)
tree
```

This will print the tree:

```
      levelName
1 Root         
2  °--1        
3      ¦--1    
4      ¦   °--1
5      °--2
```

`data.tree` provides many utility functions and properties (make sure you read the vignettes). To know the depth, in particular, use this:

```
height <- tree$height
```

Which yields:

```
> 4
```

You can then traverse the tree and find the nodes with maximum height:

```
maxDepthLeaves <- Traverse(tree, filterFun = function(node) node$level == height)
```

This traversal is the list of nodes at max level (only one `Node` in this case). You can then use `Get` to retrieve from the traversal any value, e.g. the `name`, the `position`, or the `pathString`:

```
Get(maxDepthLeaves, 'pathString')
```

Displaying as:

```
           1 
"Root/1/1/1"
```

Comment: I have gotten this far before. Having played around more with it since, I still have not figured out how to get the path/indexes to the leaves at that depth, as mentioned in my question: >_Any clue how to efficiently find the set of indexes to access the deepest values?_ Do you know of a way to achieve this taking advantage of the data.tree structure without looping over all branches manually? The heart of my question pertains to getting the location of the deepest leaves. Thank you very much for your help so far!

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. Still would like to figure out a smart way to use native lists like that at some point, but this works well for my purpose! Will mark it as answer as soon as I figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are halfway there. Whenever you find the deepest node(s), you can output the index into a list. Here's a recursive function in pseudo-code since I don't know R.

```
If tree is a leaf node
   If current depth is greater than max-depth
      Delete list of indices
      Append current index into list of indices
   If current depth is equal to max-depth
      Append current index into list of indices
Else
   for each element in the tree
      Get current index
      Recursively call this function, passing in the current index
```